# Не корректно работает fade в less

Tags: css, вёрстка, less

Мне нужно, чтоб фон становился более тусклым, я объявил переменную со цветом, добавил эту переменную в свой класс, но она применилась лишь на пол секунду и снова вернулась в исходный. Тогда я попробовал к меню применить эту переменную и она применилась. Я не понимаю логики, это только начало верстки, поэтому не могут быть перезаписывающее данное.

```css
@overlay: #252525; - color 
.site-header {
 .bg-img('hero-img.jpg');
  ///тут почему-то не работает @overlay                
}

.site-nav{
  background-color: fade(@overlay,85%);
  padding: 60px 0;
  
}//site-nav
```

Comment: `.bg-img('hero-img.jpg');` - что значит эта строчка?    
  `///тут почему-то не работает @overlay` - тут у вас его и нет